# Query Parameters with Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, coldfusion, azure-synapse, coldfusion-2016

Using ColdFusion version 16 and datasource settings:

- **Driver Class**: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
- **Driver Name**:  Microsoft SQL Server Azure

This type of query runs successfully.

```
select count(*) records
from table
where field = 'value'
```

This does not:

```
select count(*) records
from table
where field = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="value">
```

Error message is:  SCOPE_IDENTITY' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Has anyone been able to use a ColdFusion query parameter with an Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

**Edit starts here.**

Rest of error message;

> SQLSTATE   S0001
>   DATASOURCE   azuredw
>   VENDORERRORCODE   104162
>   SQL  select name from dimpatient where name = (param 1)

Start of stack trace

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 'SCOPE_IDENTITY' is not a recognized built-in function name.   
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:393)
    at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunPreparedStatement.execute(JRunPreparedStatement.java:101)
```

Comment: I dont see scope_identity anywhere in the code - are you sure its not somewhere else on the page?

Comment: Weird. The actual query is really a `select`? I could see it with an `insert` since CF may add scope_identity() to get the new record id. Though I'm surprised it doesn't support scope_identity().  I thought some versions of sqldw did...

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is supported in Azure DB, but not Azure Warehouse per the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. If you are using the `result` attribute in `cfquery` AND you were doing an `INSERT`, CF would automatically call `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the new ID as part of the struct returned by that attribute. Do you have that attribute defined? If so and it's throwing this error, then it's definitely a bug on CF's side. If not, then maybe it's an issue with the DB driver? You might try the MS JDBC driver.

Comment: Wait, Dan are you already using the MS JDBC driver?

Comment: The driver particulars are included in the question.   As far as scope identity being elsewhere on the page, The only thing on the page is a select query and a `cfdump` tag.  My intent was to check out a co-worker's statement that query parameters were an issue.

Comment: Query params shouldn't have anything to do with scope_identity(). Can you post the full error message and trace? What happens if you reduce the query down to only the query param:  `<cfquery name="qTest">SELECT <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="value"> AS ValueTest</cfquery>`.

Comment: *(Edit) You didn't mention if the cfquery is using the "result" attribute*.  Aside from that I don't see anything obvious that would be calling scope_identity() or why query params would change that. For grins, try using "Disable Autogenerated Keys" in the DSN just to see if there's any change.  Also I'd use SQL Profiler to view the actual statements are actually hitting the SQL Server.